# Adding values based on other values but SUMIF is quite right

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-HC2tAAhR3sv-vpeoHnUKksjXx44n22hiiovNa_51sU/edit?usp=sharing) is a link to my spreadsheet. Essentially what I am looking for is if the task matches then I want to also be able to give a Tech level then from there add up the values. I put a note in the sheet but basically if I give a task value and a tech level I want the corresponding value but whenever I try to do multicolumn adding in my `sumif` it just gives me the value from the first column.

An example of the formula I want is something like `=SUMIF(Name, Name2 and Rank, Add Values)`.

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: @player0 Sorry, I fixed that. I haven't used Sheets in years so I thought anyone with the link could see it.

Comment: Does `Name` stand for `Task`, and `Rank` stand for `Tech`? What do you mean by 'add up'? Please provide an example including both criteria and desired output.

Comment: @idfurw Sorry, I put a better example in the sheets which shows the data. Would you mind looking at that?

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(K3:K&"♥"&L3:L, SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 IF(B2:D="",,A2:A&"♥"&B1:D1&"×"&B2:D)), "×"), 2, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: What do the hearts do?

Comment: @Hercislife ♥ is just a unique symbol. you can use instead any you wish: ♫☼►♂♀♦♣♠...

Comment: Okay, that's what I figured but also wasn't sure if I was correct haha.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for can be done by using a Index-Match function.

e.g. If you paste the following formula in an empty cell somewhere in the sheet,

```
=INDEX($A$1:$D$8, MATCH("Task 1",$A$1:$A$8,0),MATCH("Tech 2",$A$1:$D$1,0))
```

it gives you 20 corresponding to Task 1 and Tech 2.

If you paste the following in an empty cell somewhere in sheet,

```
=INDEX($A$1:$D$8, MATCH("Task 7",$A$1:$A$8,0),MATCH("Tech 3",$A$1:$D$1,0))
```

it gives you 36 corresponding to Task 7 and Tech 3.